# Is my screen glitching out an integrated graphics issue? Windows issue? Software issue?

Tags: windows-10, gpu

### Specs

OS: windows 10

CPU: Intel Pentium G4560

Ram: 8GB

Storage: 110 GB SSD

### Problem

The issue is that the screen glitches out (very similarly to a graphics card issue), but only when I am **not** moving a window around. If I am moving a window around in a circle, the glitches disappear.

---

https://i.imgur.com/sgwD8Lo.gifv

Please forgive the watermark and general terrible quality of this gif. It is useful in illustrating the problem.

---

### What I have tried

1. Reinstalling windows numerous times
2. Updating graphics driver
3. Sending motherboard back to be repaired
4. Updating windows.
5. Running windows memory diagnostics.

---

### What I think

I think that it is most likely a hardware issue, but the fact that it can be stopped by moving the window around perplexes me. I would like someone to confirm that it is indeed hardware before I send my CPU back to intel.

Comment: Have you tried running with a single memory module at a time, or different memory modules? A memory test does not guarantee good memory. If you get different behavior it can help to narrow down a motherboard/ram/slot issue.

Comment: Yes; This is a hardware issue most definitely

Comment: @Ramhound what would explain the fact it disappears when moving a window around? Have any ideas?

Comment: @Appleoddity tested all ram slots and both stick of ram I have. I sadly don’t have any extra DDR4 to test with as this is my fathers computer.

Comment: Could be as simple as a bad cable to a bent pin if this wasn’t a soldered cpu which means it could be a bad solder joint.  The fact it stil exists after a motherboard repair tells me they sent you the same motherboard back which was a complete waste of your time

Comment: @Ramhound that’s why I’m assuming it’s a CPU issue. Because I’d assume that Gigabyte tested it when I sent it back. Could that be possible?

Comment: Your GPU is intergrated into the CPU I guarantee Gigabyte didn’t do any testing based on the fact you still have a hardware problem